# Can you weaken a stud by drilling too close to the edge?

Tags: studs

I wasn't exactly looking for a stud, was hanging a frame so I just used anchors. **Drilled 3/16" holes** for the anchors, but I am pretty sure I hit a stud. If I did indeed hit a stud, and somehow drilled at the edge of it, could I weaken it or do anything that could matter? What would be the biggest hole you can drill through the stud near the edge without weakening it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will removing shelving screws from studs damage the studs?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/172106/will-removing-shelving-screws-from-studs-damage-the-studs)

Answer (score 3):

Any hole *will weaken it.* That sized hole is unlikely to weaken it **enough to matter** (I've see bigger knotholes on the edge of graded framing lumber, for instance.) Particularly if drilled to proper depth (you should not be drilling more than 1-3/4" into a wall, so 1.25" into framing with typical 1/2 sheetrock, without knowing EXACTLY where your hole is going, due to the way plumbing and electrical codes are written for wire and pipe protection.)

*Always a good idea to look for studs when drilling walls, whether to hit them or miss them.*

Answer (score 2):

About 1/2 inch for a notch, 1/3 of the thickness.

Usually no problem for a stud.

There can be a big problem if drilling into a wall and hit an electrical cable/wire, which can be near/on/in a stud.

Electrical cables or pipes closer than an 1 and 1/2 inch to the face of a stud should have a steel plate protecting them from screws/nails. Electric cables going on the side will not have this protection.

Comment: Electric cables going along the side are supposed to be located at least 1-1/2" from the face, for that reason.